# How to select a dropdown item from listbox in cypress

Tags: cypress

I have dropdown list where in html it is specified as "role = listbox" and I want to select any specified item from dropdown.
I tried with cy.get(....).click() to first click on dropdown and then click on dropdown with .contains

```
            importp.product().click()
            .get('[class="visible menu transition"]')
             .contains("Reading").trigger('mousemove')
             .click();
```

Comment: Does this help: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select.html#Examples?

Comment: Can you please share the html of the drop down in the question

Comment: @Sree.Bh It helped me to resolve